# Perl program to read from a file which contains different email IDs from different domains

Tags: regex, perl

Perl program to read from a file which contains different email IDs from different domains. And list the username by removing the domain part.

Example:

Input file will contain:

```
abc@gmail.com 
xyz@yahoo.com 
pqr@test.com
```

The output file should look like:

```
The domain gmail.com contains following userid: 
abc 
The domain yahoo.com contains following userid: 
xyz 
The domain test.com contains following userid:
pqr
```

I tried using the code but it is only separating domain and user name, but not listing user names according to domain name.

```
use strict;
print "Enter the file name where emailids of different domains are present\n";
my $file=<stdin>;
open(DATA, "$file") or die ("Could not open the file\n");
while(<DATA>){
    my @field=split(/@/, "$_" );
    chomp $_;
    my $username=@field[0];
    my $domain=@field[1];
    print "The user id is $username \nThe domain name is $domain \n";
}
close (DATA);
```

Comment: `use warnings;`, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep to the point, you want to to populate a hash of arrays instead of printing as you find the addresses:

```
my %domains;

while(<DATA>){
  my @field=split(/@/, "$_" );
  chomp $_;
  my $username=$field[0];
  my $domain=$field[1];
  #print "The user id is $username \nThe domain name is $domain \n";
  push @{$domains{$domain}}, $username;
}
close (DATA); 

for my $domain (sort keys %domains) {
  print "The domain gmail.com contains following userid:\n";
  print "$_\n" for sort @{$domains{$domain}};
}
```

---

And to indulge in this-is-how-I'd-do-it:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use common::sense;
use Email::Address;
use YAML 'Dump';

die "usage: $0 <file1> [<file2> ... <fileN>]\n" unless @ARGV;
# although <> reads STDIN in the absense of @ARGV,
# which is often what you want.

my %hosts;

while (<>) {
  for (Email::Address->parse($_)) {
    push @{$hosts{$_->host}}, $_->user
  }
}

print Dump \%hosts;
```

Given a file named 'file', containing:

```
abc @gamil.com 
abd @gamil.com 
abe @gamil.com 
xyz@yahoo.com 
xy1@yahoo.com 
xy2@yahoo.com 
pqr@test.com 
pqs@test.com 
pqt@test.com
```

This is the usage and output:

```
$ perl test
usage: test <file1> [<file2> ... <fileN>]
$ perl test file
---
gamil.com:
  - abc
  - abd
  - abe
test.com:
  - pqr
  - pqs
  - pqt
yahoo.com:
  - xyz
  - xy1
  - xy2
```

[YAML](https://metacpan.org/module/YAML)'s readable and useful.  [Email::Address](https://metacpan.org/module/Email%3a%3aAddress) saves us trouble, now and in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You have few mistakes in your code:

1. You need to escape `@` inside strings as `\@`.
2. To define Perl array, you use `@array`. But to address elements in array, you need to use `$`: `$array[0]`.

This means, your code should look like this:

```
use strict;
print "Enter the file name where emailids of different domains are present\n";
my $file=<stdin>;
open DATA, "$file" or die $!;
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($username, $domain) = split /\@/, $line;
    print "The user id is $username \nThe domain name is $domain \n";
}
close DATA;
```

I have simplified few things, like use `$line` instead of `$_` to make it more clear, and to save results of split into variables right away, rather than creating extra array.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
my $file=<stdin>;
my %hash;
open(DATA, "$file") or die ("Could not open the file\n");
while(<DATA>){ 
  chomp($_);
  my @field=split(/\@/, "$_" );
  chomp(@fields);
  push(@{$hash{$field[1]}},@field);
}
close (DATA);
```

you have all the domains in a hash and its user names as it value that is an array reference . you can either iterate it or use Dumper